Cannot get a simple cube to load using React-Three-Fiber
I am using the react-three-fiber getting started doc to render a cube on a page but nothing shows and I am at a bit of a loss.
Link: https://r3f.docs.pmnd.rs/getting-started/your-first-scene
I am getting this error and a blank page in the browser:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.ReactCurrentBatchConfig')
I am getting these warming in the Webpack build but I believe these have nothing to do with my issue:
WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/events-321b05fb.esm.js 2260:12-30
export 'unstable_act' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __CLIENT_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_WARN_USERS_THEY_CANNOT_UPGRADE, act, cache, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, startTransition, unstable_useCacheRefresh, use, useActionState, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useDeferredValue, useEffect, useId, useImperativeHandle, useInsertionEffect, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useOptimistic, useReducer, useRef, useState, useSyncExternalStore, useTransition, version)
 @ ./node_modules/@react-three/fiber/dist/react-three-fiber.esm.js 1:0-228 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 2:0-557 215:11-30 236:22-28 249:30-48 258:2-27 261:40-50 281:85-90 298:35-48 301:39-44 312:29-51
 @ ./frontend/components/three_components/Cube.jsx 1:0-44 5:38-44
 @ ./frontend/components/App.jsx 1:0-47 3:42-46
 @ ./frontend/main.js 3:0-39 5:45-48

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  bundle.js (984 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (984 KiB)
      bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Here is my code:
my app component
import Cube from './three_components/Cube.jsx';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Cube />
  );
};

export default App;


my cube component
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';

function Cube(props) {
  return (
    <div id='container'>
      <Canvas>
        <mesh>
          <boxGeometry args={[2, 2, 2]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial />
        </mesh>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
        <directionalLight color='red' position={[0, 0, 5]} />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cube;


my main.js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

let root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))


root.render(
      <App />
);



I tried deleting node-modules and package-lock.json but it had no effect.
looking up .ReactCurrentBatchConfig doesn't provide anything meaningful.

I have found the solution for my question.
it seems that react-three-fiber has conflicts with React 19. so by installing '@react-three/fiber@alpha' seems to fix the issue

npm install @react-three/fiber@alpha

here is the link to where I found the answer:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/66468#issuecomment-2296319798
thanks for all the answers!

I don't see your Tree. But I can assume that the problem lies in the Cube.jsx import. I suspect that you have it placed in three_components. App.jsx and Cube.jsx are both located in the src/components/ folder, making them sibling files. So, the relative path ./Cube.jsx is right one.
Try this structure, it tested and works.
Tree
project-folder/
├── public/
│   └── index.html
├── src/
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── App.jsx
│   │   └── Cube.jsx
│   ├── main.js
│   └── index.css
├── package.json
└── README.md

App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Cube from './Cube';

Cube.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';

main.js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';

